# New command to display a symbol and its command

Tags: macros, symbols

I'd like to print a symbol and the command to get the symbol. For example,`\bomb\ (\verb|\bomb|)`. To make a command to save some keystrokes, I came up with this command `\newcommand{\symb}[1]{#1\ (\verb|#1|)}`.
However, I get some compilation error `\verb ended by end of line.` with wrong results.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\newcommand{\symb}[1]{#1\ (\verb|#1|)}

\begin{document}

Fourier
\begin{itemize}
    \item \symb{\danger}
    \item \bomb\ (\verb|\bomb|)
    \item \grimace\ (\verb|\grimace|)
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

What's wrong and what might be the solution?

Comment: You can't use `\verb` inside of a macro, as generally verbatim content is not possible, at least not this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is too late to use `\verb` after the argument has been tokenised but you can do:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\newcommand{\symb}[1]{#1\ (\texttt{\string#1})}

\begin{document}

Fourier
\begin{itemize}
    \item \symb{\danger}
    \item \bomb\ (\verb|\bomb|)
    \item \grimace\ (\verb|\grimace|)
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```