# Command to display and execute code (math formulae)

Tags: listings, code, rendering

Similar to [New command to display a symbol and its command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411307/new-command-to-display-a-symbol-and-its-command) I would like to have a command to display and execute code. The code should be displayed with the listings package.

For example something like

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,listings}
\newcommand*{\codeExample}[1]{Code: \lstinline!\string{#1}! yields #1}
\begin{document}
  \codeExample{$\lVert a\rVert$}
\end{document}
```

should for best of cases display `$\lVert a \rVert$` as verbatim (`\lstinline!...!`) code and after that the rendered math code. Is something like that possible? The code above yields several mistakes. I think I miss something to avoid `#1` being tokenised?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `xparse` verbatim arguments for that.

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\codeExample{v}{%
    Code: \texttt{#1} yields \scantokens{#1\noexpand}%
}
\begin{document}
  \codeExample{$\lVert a\rVert$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ...and that again also works with `\lstinline[language={[LaTeX]TeX}]{#1}` instead of the `\texttt` (which I prefer for further markup). Great!

Comment: @Henri Could you please explain the need  for `\noexpand`? It seems to work without it too.

Comment: @Henri Is `\scantokens`  a kind of reverse operation to `\detokenize`?

Comment: @AlexG http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/doc/etex/etex_man.pdf 3.7 Input Handling

Comment: @AlexG See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117906/use-of-everyeof-and-endlinechar-with-scantokens. The effect of that here is that the version with `\noexpand` doesn't add an extra space when the `\scantokens` is processed.

Comment: @siracusa Thank you for sharing the link! Interesting read. Now I understand better.

Comment: Please note that this usage of `\scantokens` might break things (e.g., try `\codeExample|abc|\\`). While the `\noexpand` is supposed to fix the `\scantokens` eof-leakage, it also breaks immediately following macros, you can use `\scantokens{#1\noexpand}\relax` as a quick-fix for this instead.

Comment: That should have been `\codeExample|abc|\\ `.

Answer (score 1):

Since `\scantokens` is really hard to use right, I'd advocate to use the `expl3` implementation of it that takes care of all the pitfalls. So all in all, this is the same as [@HenriMenke's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/506042/117050), but more robust:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\codeExample{v}
  {
    Code:~\texttt{#1}~yields~\tl_rescan:nn {} {#1}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
  \codeExample{$\lVert a\rVert$}
\end{document}
```

[image]